# geojson not rendering in mapbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

here i am using reverse geocoding i am trying to render map of user location by sending latitude and logitude to reverse geocoding api but it is not rendring only starting coordinates used as center is rendered

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";



import "./map.css";

mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN;

function Map() {
  const [mapData, setMapdata] = useState(null);
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const popUpRef = useRef(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 15 }));

 // initialize map when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainerRef.current,
      // See style options here: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#styles
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [85, 27], // starting position
      zoom: 12.5,
});

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        map.on("load", function () {
     
          map.addSource("myLocation", {
            type: "geojson",
            // Use a URL for the value for the `data` property.
            data:`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${position.coords.latitude},
                  ${position.coords.longitude}.json? 
                  access_token=${process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
          });
        });
    });
}




    // clean up on unmount
    return () => map.remove();
  }, []); 

  return <div className="map-container" ref={mapContainerRef} />;
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the datasource to a layer. To display a source, you must add a layer and set the `source` attribute to your datasource.

Try adding something along the lines of:

```
    map.addLayer({
        id: 'locations',
        source: 'myLocation',
        // everthing beyond this point is styling/customization
        type: 'circle',
        paint: {
            'circle-color': '#ff0000',
            'circle-radius': 6,
            'circle-stroke-width': 2,
            'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
        }
    });
```

More info on layers, including styling/customization can be found here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/

Comment: its not working i don't know what was the problem and i could not find any solution all over the net .mapbox always render starting coordinates